# Хороший тон программирования

Tags: хороший-тон, php, mysql

У меня такой вопрос(ы).

1. Обязательно ли закрывать соединение `mysql_close($conn)`?
2. -//- Вызывать сборщик мусора `mysql_free_result()`?

К чему может привести невыполнение этих правил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-close.php

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-free-result.php

По обоим ссылкам читайте последний абзац блока "описание". Не думаю, что кто-то скажет больше)

От себя:

1. Использовать их стоит только в режиме "paranoid coding", первое - когда выборки возвращают огромное количество данных, второе - когда у ват бешеное кол-во соединений с БД на единицу времени и работа с БД - не основная часть работы скрипта.
2. Я первой пользовался при работе с 16-гиговой базой, второй - ни разу.